# How can I redirect my homepage to another URL?

Tags: html, .htaccess

my homepage is currently `website.com`

but I would like the homepage to be `website.com/home`, and if anyone visits `website.com` I want them to be redirected to `website.com/home`.

how is this achieveable through .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your .htaccess you should have something like this:

- Redirect /oldfile.html http://websitename.com/newfile.html

Used as reference this guys who also provided a good example of HowTo: 
http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F

Comment: this causes a redirect loop

Comment: Are you redirecting to the same page? like websiteName to websiteName?<br> You should probably show us how the structure of your files. PS: you have to put even the extension so use newName.html instead of just newName

Comment: Good point! I'll edit my anwer and i'll try to improve my answers from now on.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website.com/home [R=301,L]
```

You should put it in a .htaccess file on website.com

Comment: "This web page has a redirect loop"

Comment: You may want to check if there is a rule inside website.com/home that redirects back to website.com

Comment: that code actually made every page on the website break. every page brought up the redirect loop message

Comment: RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ /home [L]

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, you can add this in your head section :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/index" />
```

Comment: Why -1, I don't understand ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Redirect 301 website.com/ website.com/home/

or

Redirect 301 / website.com/home/